# Higher dimensional supergravity d.o.f

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom, supergravity

From where do the antisymmetric tensor d.o.f. arises from superpoincare group in 10 and 11 dimensional ${\cal N}=1$ SUGRAs? I mean, beyond the d.o.f. matching. Why it need's to be antisymmetric?

Comment: Do you have an alternative model to [CJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_supergravity#The_mathematics) with perfect d.o.f. matching  and in a rep of the Poincare?

Comment: Can you recast your question in the language of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3502)? Are you asking how it was discovered, or why nothing else has been, since?

Comment: I am asking how can be constructed the gravity supermultiplet, a little related in how it was discovered. Why 'nothing else', is outside my interest.

Comment: Try learning how other, simpler supermultiplets are constructed. You start with the highest spin state and descend by successive applications if busy generators. That's why (Pascal's triangle) the multiplicities matter. Given the multiplicities, it is child's play to accommodate them into Lorentz tensors and spinors. You then confirm your busy transformations (with blood, sweat and tears, to be sure) and you are done, unless you fail, which is why the "nothing else" matters. Most good reviews and books on sugra do this, and a question here is asking for an impossible summary  tutorial.

Comment: The way I learned is: you take a lorentz rep and you lower down it's spin with $Q^\alpha$, until you can't lower down it anymore. What I don't understand is how to get the missing d.o.f.'s when your higher spin rep lacks d.o.f.s to match the lower d.o.f.s. Where can I read about that?

Comment: I am not familiar with the plethora of books and reviews that have populated the market in the intervening 40 years... But *some* of them surely illustrate the hit-or-miss sudoku-like procedure: review first how the N=8, D=4 theory was put together, and the rest should come easily.

Comment: Finally I understood: N=1 supersymmetry in ten dimensions has four independent $Q_\alpha$ generators that mutually anticonmute, so... Lowering down can happen four times and so on and so on.

Comment: Indeed, indeed....